# Using DATEPART in sql statement to get records with specific year

Tags: asp-classic, datepart

In Classic ASP:

I can extract the year from a date/time field:

```
tester=rs.fields("datestamp")
tester=DATEPART("yyyy",tester)
```

But I cannot seem to figure out how to make this work in a SQL statement to bring all the records from a specific year:

```
Select * from table1 where DATEPART("yyyy",datestamp)='2012'
```

and this doesn't work either:

```
Select * from table1 where DATEPART("yyyy",datestamp)=2012
```

I've looked through a zillion examples, here and elsewhere, and can't seem to find one that'll make this work.  What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What is the column type of `datestamp`?

Comment: datestamp is a data type date/time in the access database...

Comment: well, a friend pointed out that this seems to do it:
Select * from table1 WHERE year(datestamp) =2012
Though I'm still curious what the syntax would be with DATEPART

Comment: You could just use `Select * from table1 where datestamp like '%2012%'`

Comment: Looking at this link it appears you need hashes around your date if you use datepart http://www.techonthenet.com/access/functions/date/datepart.php.  Also, don't forget you need to escape double quotes if you're using ASP/VBScript, so at a guess you would use `SQL="Select * from table1 where DATEPART(""yyyy"",#datestamp#)='2012'"` - which looks hideous and open to syntax error

Comment: @John only if it's a static value, you you pass a variable (like a column name) the hash is not required. I think it maybe the `[]` brackets around the column name the OP is missing `SQL="Select * from table1 where DATEPART(""yyyy"", [datestamp])=""2012"""`.

Comment: @John OP could also use `YEAR([datestamp]) = 2012`.

Answer (score 0):

The function DatePart can extract from any date some values.
The best explanation that i know is here: [W3School.com](http://www.w3schools.com/asp/func_datepart.asp)

And this command can be used as a part of SQL string as you want, but in this case you must considerer that the main parameter change.
Sample for filter by Month for less that June:

```
DATEPART(month, yourvar_withdate) <= 6
```

Check this explanation: [W3School.com-SQL](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_datepart.asp)

Sure that you need use a number without quotes to eval. You can check "yy" or year (without quotes) to verify.

One more note, you must have always content on DateStamp field or receive an error.